# No envía notificación push

Tags: php

Estoy intentando enviar un mensaje por GCM pero no se envía nada, y aunque no me da error la variable:

```
$result
```

al imprimirla da "to", no tengo la menor idea de por que.

Mi código para enviar el mensaje es:

```
private function sendMessageGcm($registration_id,$message){             
  $this->key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  $data = array(
    "registration_id" => $registration_id,
    "data" => $message
  );
  $headers = array(
    "Content-Type:application/json",
    "Authorization:key=" . $this->key
  );
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  if($result == false) {
    echo('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
  }
  curl_close($ch);
  $rtn["code"] = "000";//means result OK
  $rtn["msg"] = "OK";
  $rtn["result"] = $result;
  return($rtn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, hace unos meses integre de la misma forma un web worker para utilizar push notifications, en general no pareceria estar mal tu script pero te hago 2 comentarios. Por un lado no veo que estes decodificando la respuesta (viene en un formato JSON) y por otro veo que estas poniendo de forma fija (harcodeando) la URL del endpoint.

**Verificar respuesta**

Intenta agregar este codigo al final de tu script para depurar la respuesta del mismo.

```
if (!empty($result)){
    $json_response = json_decode($result, true);
    if (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE){
        if ($json_response["failure"] == 1){
            echo "Error";
        }else{
            echo "Success";
        }
    }
    print_r($result);
}
```

**Endpoint URL**

Apesar de que en las pruebas todas las URLs de los diferentes endpoints parecen ser iguales (como si solo se alterara el token) te confirmo que esto no es consistente. Tengo una base de datos con cerca de 20.000 endpoints y las URLs varian. Por ende, deberias hacer este llamado curl utilizando el endpoint del cliente y no estableciendolo en fijo.

Te dejo una funcion muy util que tuve que crear en mi proyecto para separar cualquier endpoint en URL y TOKEN ID. A esta funcion basicamente le pasas el endpoint del cliente y te devuelve un array con los 2 datos que necesitas para hacer el push.

```
function fn_get_endpoint($endpoint_url){
    if (empty($endpoint_url)){
        return false;
    }
    $tmp = explode("/", $endpoint_url);
    if(count($tmp) == 1){
        return false;
    }
    $response = array();
    $response["id"] = $tmp[count($tmp)-1];
    $response["endpoint"] = preg_replace("/\/$/", "", preg_replace("/".$response["id"]."/", "", $endpoint_url));
    return $response;
}
```